# How to convert iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.GenericSecretKey as java.security key

Tags: java, cryptography, iaik-jce

I want to convert iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.GenericSecretKey(AES) as java.security key.

Comment: Cool. Can you provide examples of what you have done so far? 

Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible, but let's explore some posibilities none-the-less.

Note that it depends on the token type and software / provider if these possibilities are supported at all, but you can certainly try.

---

Directly using the reference is probably not possible, as you must be able to use the HSM operations. So even though you can possibly embed the key in a `SecretKey` object, you'd still not be able to use it. You would need a provider specific API to pull that off. Hey, maybe it exists.

---

PKCS#11 objects, including keys, are generally stored on a HSM or other security token. Secret keys can generally not be extracted easily.

You can also sometimes make the keys extractable by setting the attribute `CKA_EXTRACTABLE` to true (and `CKA_SENSITIVE` to false during generation. This will of course also have a negative influence on the security of the key. If you can get this to work (depending on the PKCS#11 token implementation) then you should be able to copy the key value to memory.

You may also be able to *wrap* the key with a wrapping key known by you and the HSM extract the keys that way.

It should be easy to simply call a `SecretKeySpec` constructor with the value once you've been able to obtain it to convert it to `SecretKey`.

---

Generally it is easier to generate the keys locally (using the HSM's random number generator of the token, where required and available). Then you can import them and set `CKA_SENSITIVE` to `true` afterwards. Of course, `CKA_ALWAYS_SENSITIVE` will stay set to `false` (and `CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE` will stay set to `true`) if you do so.

---

By far the easiest and most secure way to do this is to generate the key using a provider supplied `KeyGenerator`, forgoing the `GenericSecretKey` method in the question, where available. However, this side-steps the question.